Should I upload the compressed files installed with zero install from yarn berry to the git repository?
Should I upload the compressed files installed with zero install from yarn berry to the git repository?
I'm trying to upload a project set up with yarn berry to a git repository, but there are 1410 unstaged files. Do I need to upload all of these zero-install compressed files so that other people can completely clone the repository?
I'm trying to commit all files to the repository, but I'm having trouble figuring out what to do with the 1410 unstaged files.

Are those unstaged files product of building the project?
